# How to group a value(s) in a table based on a condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with values as given below:

```
MemberID    Location        DateJoined
79925        183            2013-07-01 00:00:00.000 
79925        184            2013-07-02 00:00:00.000
65082        184            2012-07-22 00:00:00.000
72046        183            2013-05-01 00:00:00.000 
72046        184            2013-05-10 00:00:00.000 
...
```

Here i need to check if the above table has locationID 183 & 184.
Based on these results i need to create a new table as below given

```
MemberID    Benifit
79925        Yes
65082        No
72046        Yes
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you well

```
select MemberID, case when Sum(x) = 2 then 'YES' else 'No' end Benifit from
(
  SELECT *, CASE WHEN Location in (183,184) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS x
  FROM MyTable
) t
group t by MemberID
```

Comment: Thank you so much RezaRahmati.  You are absolutely correct

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO table2 (MemberID, Benifit)
SELECT t1.MemberID, 
CASE WHEN t2.MemberID IS NULL OR t3.MemberID IS NULL THEN 'NO' ELSE 'YES' END AS Benefit
FROM table1 t1
 LEFT JOIN table1 t2 ON (t2.MemberID = t1.MemberID AND t2.Location = 183)
 LEFT JOIN table1 t3 ON (t3.MemberID = t1.MemberID AND t3.Location = 184)
WHERE t1.Location IN (183,184)
GROUP BY t1.MemberID, t2.MemberID, t3.MemberID
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ece758/7

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you wanted to show all members that had locations 183 **and** 184. You could do something like this:

The `INTERSECT` subquery will return all MemberID's that associated with both 183 and 184 locations, and the `CASE` will display the Yes or No.

```
SELECT
  MemberID,
  CASE
   WHEN MemberID IN
    (SELECT MemberID FROM Table WHERE Location = 183
     INTERSECT
     SELECT MemberID FROM Table WHERE Location = 184)
     THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END as 'Benefit'
FROM Table
```

Simply using `WHERE Location in (183,183)` will show you MemberIDs that are in either location, but not necessarily both.

Comment: Hi LCIII,  your solution is as well correct in first case we are summing the location which is same as intersect in your query.